# Getting part of query defined by a parameterized function

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, procedures, table-functions

Hello all :) I'm try to do something like this in Oracle 10g:

```
SELECT 
  CAR_ID,
  CAR_DATE,
  get_some_other_info(CAR_TYPE)
FROM CARS
```

Where `get_some_other_info(CAR_ID)` would return several columns:

```
| CAR_ID | CAR_DATE   | CAR_COLOR | CAR_CO2
| 001    | 01/01/2013 | BLUE      | 100
| 002    | 02/01/2013 | RED       | 120
| 003    | 03/01/2013 | BLUE      | 100
```

I need to use a function for implementation reasons. I feel that I could use [Table functions](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/pipelined-table-functions.php#table_functions), but I cannot wrap my head around how to use them for my case.

Best regards,

Comment: Number of columns has to be known when a query is executed and they must be specified in your `SELECT` list. What you can do is either: a) call separate function for each "column" that you want to get (bad idea because of performance issues) or b) return aggregated value and in outer query retrieve values from it, each into a separate column (feels like a poor design).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use dynamic SQL to accomplish that. Concatenate the result of your function with a variable containing your SQL then run it with execute immediate.
Google it and you'll find a lot of examples.